# Jordan Block of a complex matrix, with $A^4=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, block-matrices

The following statement is false or true:

> If $A \in M(n, \mathbb{C})$ is a matrix with complex entries of order $n$ such that $A^4=I$ then
>   \begin{pmatrix}
> i & 1\\ 
> 0 & i
> \end{pmatrix}
>   Can be a Jordan Block of $A$.

I believe this statement is false, but I could not formalize the demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that

$$A^4=I\implies (A-I)(A+I)(A^2+I)=(A-I)(A+I)(A-iI)(A+iI)$$

Thus, over $\;\Bbb C\;$ , the matrix's minimal polynomial decomposes as a product of different linear factors and is thus diagonalizable, which means it cannot have a Jordan Block as the one you wrote.

Comment: Yes, except you're  not saying what you mean. In fact $(A-I)(A+I)(A^2+I)=(A-I)(A+I)(A-iI)(A+iI)$ regardless of whether $A^4=I$; also a polynomial cannot be diagonalizable.

Comment: I had thought of that, but I thought more arguments were needed. Thank you @DonAntonio

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich 1) That decomposition you mention is due **precisely** to the fact that $\;A^4=I\;$ . It is not independent of it but resulting from it, (2) Yes, my grammar made it sound like the polynomial is the one which is (or is not) diagonalizable, but making a little effort, like the OP did, I think it can be understood correctly...in particular because immediately before that I wrote " the **matrix's** polynomial..." . The OP had to round up and finish the argument: a square matrix is diagonalizable  iff its minimal polynomial can be written as a product of *different* linear factors.

Comment: "That decomposition you mention is due precisely to the fact that $A^4=I$. It is not independent of it but resulting from it," What??? Can you give an example of $A$ where $(A-I)(A+I)(A^2+I)\ne(A-I)(A+I)(A-iI)(A+iI)$? No. What's due to $A^4=I$ is the fact that $(A-I)(A+I)(A-iI)(A+iI)=0$. Which of course is what matters, but which you didn't mention  explicitly.

Comment: " I think it can be understood correctly": Yes of course. I didn't say it couldn't be understood correctly, I said that you didn't say what you meant.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I've no idea what you're talking about, honestly. Have a good day.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be unclear. The identity $(A-I)(A+I)(A^2+I)=(A-I)(A+I)(A-iI)(A+iI)$ holds for every square matrix $A$, so saying it depends on $A^4=I$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach: we have $B = iI + N$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix and we have
$$
N = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.
$$
Notably, $iI$ and $N$ commute (so the binomial theorem applies) and $N^2 = 0$.  Thus, we have
$$
B^4 = (iI + N)^4 = (iI)^4 + 4(iI)^3N + 6(0) + 4(0) + 0 = I -4i N\\
= \pmatrix{1&-4i\\0&1}.
$$
Thus, if $B$ is a Jordan block of the Jordan form $J$ of $A$, then $J^4$ will have $B^4$ as a diagonal submatrix.  So, we cannot have $J^4 = I$.  It follows that $A^4 \neq I$.